# PowerShell to check the string in the array

Tags: powershell, vsphere, powercli

I have a output of PowerCLI stored in a variable. I want to check the string is present in the string, if present continue with for loop.

Below is my script:

```
$stringtosearch = "test"
$getds = Get-Datastore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
if ($dsname -contains $getds) {
    Write-Host "datastore exists"
    continue
}
```

The above script is not getting into loop and continuing for loop.

Comment: `$dsname -match $getds` or `$dsname -like "*$getds*"`

Comment: There is no loop in the code you posted, so what are you even talking about?

Comment: While the linked post is about arrays, the same misconception underlies it: `-contains` doesn't perform _substring_ matching - only array membership.